# Multiconfiguration and Jenkins pipeline Jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, multi-configuration

I have an application which needs to be tested for several architectures (Centos5, Centos6, Centos7); 
I implemented a `Jenkinsfile` in which I run the set of tests for the chosen a architecture target.
Now I want to somehow run these tests for all target architectures. How can I achieve this?

I was told that I need to investigate about Jenkins multi-configuration projects, but all the examples I could find are about Java based projects only. And if this is the approach to be used, how can I call my Jenkins script with different input parameter values?

I will appreciate if someone could provide me some hints on where to start and with which Jenkins plugins. 
thanks 
Now, I want to achieve a matrix based approach, namely build 
I have written a Jenkins pipeline which builds an application.

Comment: Could you share some code please?

Comment: @/blazej-checinski: Hi, in the end, here is what I did:
I implemented a Groovy file, with a main function which is then called by different pipeline scripts with the appropriate parameters. It works nicely.